# How can I enable SSL on my Apache for more than one port? (Got an eror)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, apache-virtualhost

I need to enable SSL for more ports than 443. I've tried it this way:

First I've added the port to my ports.conf

```
Listen 8081
```

After this I've edited my vHost in my Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>

    Here are my other settings.... (not important I think)

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /the/certificate/file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /the/key/file
</VirtualHost>
```

After this I've tried to restart my apache but it says config error and the server won't start again. Before I've tried to add SSL my vHost worked so the problem is not my other configuration.

In the error log I found this here: Caught SIGTERM, shutting down

I'm currently runnning the standard SSL port 443 for my website and configured this in the standard SSL config from apache.

******** UPDATE ********

This is the full config file:

```
# phpMyAdmin default Apache configuration

<VirtualHost *:8081>
    Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin

    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
        Allow from 127.0.0.1

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile .....
        SSLCertificateKeyFile .....

        Options FollowSymLinks
        DirectoryIndex index.phpMyAdmin

        <IfModule mod_php.c>
            <IfModule mod_mine.configuration>
                AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
            </IfModule>
            <FilesMatch ".+\php$">
                SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
            </FilesMatch

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen On
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/:/usr/share/ph$
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # Authorize for setup
    <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/setup>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            <IfModule mod_authm_file.c>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "phpMyAdmin Setup"
                AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd.setup
            </IfModule>
            Require valid-user
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The stuff right before "Caught SIGTERM, shutting down" will probably be more helpful

Comment: Please run `sudo apachectl configtest` and paste the output into your question!

Comment: @Bandrami there is "mpm_prefork:notice"

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I've did this and it says Sytax error on line 12. Line 12 is  "SSLEngine On"

Comment: Please kindly add the "not important settings"!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I'll do, give my a second

Comment: Please also add the `The stuff right before "Caught SIGTERM` from error logs

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen there is no other stuff before. Thats the only log entry.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished setting up an apache2 and I updated exactly what you asked.

**ports.conf**

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
#       Listen 443
        Listen 8081
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
#       Listen 443
        Listen 8081
</IfModule>
```

**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site

        LogLevel info ssl:warn

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /your/cert.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /your/key.key

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my-site.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

ps. My `SSLEngine On` is so written, still, it works. I don't think the issue is to be searched there.

Comment: Then how come the error points to line 12, what Linux version are you using?

Comment: Does not always mean the error is there, might be on the previous row. And anyway, all my Apache2 have it mixed, `On` and `on`, I doubt it is it

Comment: Ok, if you say so!